# Return Title Record With Cast using Netflix OData Service

Tags: linq, odata

Is there a way to return a result set made up of a Title record and the associated Cast collection if I filter on Title.Id?

I.E., give me all Title fields where Id = "ApUFq" and associated Cast (Person) collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the query you're describing: `http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/Titles('ApUFq')?$expand=Cast`

Or in LINQ:
`from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select new {t, t.Cast}`

Comment: Thank you.  Can you help me with making that a LINQ query, so I can test with LINQPad?

Comment: `from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select new {t, t.Cast}`

Comment: Thanks so much.  Once more question, when a simple query is done.  i.e., from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select t  the result set returns 0 items in Collection Types (i.e. Cast, Directors, Genres)

Comment: Another question and not even an upvote yet? :p But seriously, yeah, that's right. If you don't include the $expand=Cast part in the URL or the t.Cast part in the LINQ query, you get a reference to the Cast collection, but not the expanded Cast collection itself.